# What do I need to enter Germany as an unaccompanied minor?

Tags: germany, paperwork, minors

I'm 16 and I'll be going to Germany alone from the U.S., but I do not know what I need to enter besides my passport. Because I am underage, do I *need* any other documents to enter the country? My parents will know that I'm going, and I'll have a place to stay at, arranged in advance. I speak a bit of German as well. I've heard from websites that you need a document of consent from your parents and other websites stating it is recommended to have such a document. Can anyone tell me what I need to have to enter the country?

Comment: Are you a US citizen ? The IO might ask for documentation but I think it's entirely up to them

Answer (score 5):

Here's what you need, according to the European Commission's [website](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/eu-citizen/germany/index_en.htm) for travel to Germany

> In addition to their own valid travel document (passport or ID card),
>   although not obligatory by law, all minors entering or leaving Germany
>   are advised to carry an [authorisation](https://www.bundespolizei.de/DE/01Buergerservice/Reiseinformationen/Passrecht/passrecht_node.html) (where possible in the
>   languages of both the home country and the destination country) signed
>   by their parents/legal guardian. The document should show:
>
> - that the minor has their permission to travel alone
> - the contact details of the parents/legal guardian

Note it says it's not obligatory, so the officer may not even ask you, but I'd say it's still a very good idea to have it on you.

Comment: The Bundespolizei page also recommends carrying a copy of the parent/guardian's passport data page.